# Wrap all elements using a div after a certain element using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to wrap all Divs that come after a specific element. How can I do this using jQuery?

**Current Code**

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
<div class="b"></div>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>

<div class="a"></div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will guess you have been downvote because you didn't show any code you have try to produce. As some other people will say. We are not here to code for you but show you your misstake.

Comment: Better late than never, here's a solution that works for future reference and anyone else who finds themselves here looking for one that the given answers don't provide: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdZpBo

Answer (score 1):

You could create wrap element for each `.a`, add all elements until next `.a` element and then add to DOM.

```js
$('.a').each(function() {
  var wrap = $('<div class="wrapper"></div>');
  $(this).nextUntil('.a').appendTo(wrap);
  $(this).after(wrap);
})
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>

<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>

<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 2 `.b`, you could use the following code:

```js
$('.a').each(function() {
    $(this).next('.b').next('.b').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>

<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>

<div class="a">A</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
<div class="b">B</div>
```